# maven install jasper report error 308: Permanent Redirect

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

I try install dependencies of my maven project but when I use "mvn install" I get this error for jasper report:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< com.projectSecret >--------------
[INFO] Building projectSecret
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from jaspersoft-third-party: http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js5/itext-2.1.7.js5.pom
Downloading from jaspersoft-third-party: http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/org/olap4j/olap4j/0.9.7.309-JS-3/olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.373 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-10T20:20:08-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project projectSecret: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.projectSecret.org:projectSecret:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.4.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js5: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js5 from/to jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/): Transfer failed for http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js5/itext-2.1.7.js5.pom 308 Permanent Redirect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

any idea why this error or solution? Thanks!

I use Linux Mint 20 and :

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-74-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

[my pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hUKpuE6oRtMxhmkyn9zSQhc4juDhGxqv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: First the itext part is available from central repository:  https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7/jar and it's important to know that central is only accessible via https instead of http....also the given url:  https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/. (https instead of http!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. It seams that iText is not availabel on public repos. Here https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues/148 the solution is to add the following repo:

```
<repository>
   <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
   <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
</repository>
```

Edit: I need to change the url from http to https.

Comment: You're a life saver <3 !